# Apple Map (MKMapView) Mercator Projection's EPSG

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview

I can't seem to find which projection Apple Map's Mercator Projection uses. Doesn't say on 
their guide:

[Location Awareness Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/MapKit/MapKit.html)

Anybody know off hand?

Comment: Can you confirm if my answer was what you needed?

Answer (score 6):

It's the same as Google's, which [EPSG:3857](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/EPSG:3857) (and unofficially 900913).

Comment: an alias for this projection, I think, is EPSG:3785/SR-ORG:6864. They both appear to have effectively the same proj4 code. The spatialreference.org description for 3785 is interesting though in that it criticizes the projection for being inaccurate by "up to 800 meters in position and up to 0.7% in scale" http://spatialreference.org/ref/sr-org/6864/