# Mercator projection of openstreetmap data

Tags: swift, openstreetmap, projection, mercator

I am trying to develop a Cyprus map for iOS devices. I have used the data found in http://openstreetmapdata.com to draw the coastline (I have used the data derived by Mercator projection, as found in the webpage). I have also used data derived from https://www.openstreetmap.org to draw the map's roads. I have used Swift function MKMapPointForCoordinate() to convert the latter to cartesian coordinates. This function converts geographic coordinates to cartesian using Mercator projection. However, these derived data and the data found in https://www.openstreetmap.org do not match (i.e., they lie in different areas). In http://openstreetmapdata.com/info/projections#mercator it is stated that EPSG code 3857 is used for Mercator projection. Furthemore, in [Apple Map (MKMapView) Mercator Projection's EPSG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16575006/apple-map-mkmapview-mercator-projections-epsg) it is stated that Apple's aforementioned function uses the same EPSG code. Does anyone know what the exactly the problem is?

Comment: Maybe you want to ask at https://gis.stackexchange.com instead

Comment: Ok, thank you for the information